# Vaio svf1521 and bluetooth problem

Tags: kubuntu, 23.04, bluetooth-speaker

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 in UEFI mode and bluetooth was not activated with the command:

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm    
sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd
```

The problem was solved and Bluetooth was activated, but the problem is that sometimes it disconnects and reconnects for no reason when playing music.
Also, while playing music, if I install a program or open Firefox or file manager or do anything else, the music stops and starts and sometimes it makes a lot of noise.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    8.373072] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.373122] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    8.373128] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.373135] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.373141] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.373148] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.619649] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    8.621408] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    8.637544] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[    8.637553] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[    8.639187] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd' Patch
[    9.382540] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    9.398549] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth Device (43142)
[    9.398559] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0280
[    9.493633] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.493645] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.493654] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.497925] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   13.366524] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   13.366540] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   13.366554] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```